# Libraries crash after installing experimental version of libc6

Tags: linux, debian, boot, libraries, glibc

My Debian system is not booting anymore after installing the experimental version of libc6.

I've got this message on boot:

```
/sbin/init: error while loading shared libraries: libsepol.so.1: 
    cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What can I do to get this resolved?

The error:
[image]

Error #2:
[image]

Comment: How did you install the libs? Support for experimental packages / libs is going to be very limited. You might be able to fix your problems with a chroot, but it might be easier to do a fresh install. I usually play with experimental things in a virtual machine (if at all) ;)

Comment: I followed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863613 , Add the following line to the file /etc/apt/sources.list:

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian experimental main
Update your package database:

apt-get update
Install the eglibc package:

apt-get -t experimental install libc6-amd64 libc6-dev libc6-dbg

Comment: Do you know how to use a chroot ?

Comment: I have not that much experience with it. Can I do it via a Live USB? How to do it?

Comment: Good rule of thumb: don't upgrade libc6. Unless you need to. And you never need to.

Comment: I did need it, to install steam..

Comment: @StephanMeijer: The correct way to do that is backport it. And it looks pretty easy to backport.

Comment: Occasionally people who think that libc is "just another dependency package" do this (once, lol).  It's a dependency alright -- *for ABSOLUTELY EVERYTHING*, except the kernel.  E-V-E-R-Y-T-H-I-N-G  **Never, ever, ever do this unless you really know what you are doing.**  You cannot fix it from within the system. TBH, I recommend you use a live CD to copy stuff you want saved out, and then install from scratch a distro that ships with the version you need.

Answer (score 3):

You can try a chroot. boot a live USB and become root

```
sudo -i
```

Mount your old system at /mnt (change sda1 as needed)

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

Prep the chroot

```
mount -o bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount -o bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys

cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf
```

Enter the chroot

```
chroot /mnt /bin/bash
```

Assuming that goes well, remove the experimental repository and try running

```
apt-get update
apt-get -t stable install libc6-amd64 libc6-dev libc6-dbg
```

You may need to specify the old versions of those packages , see https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get

Use apt-cache to search for the package versions

```
apt-cache search libc6-amd64
```

If all that fails, you probably need to consider backing up your data and re-installing.

Comment: This failed, error picture here: http://oi42.tinypic.com/35a4s5z.jpg

Comment: See my update (there was a typo)

Comment: Thanks, but still the same error while running "chroot /mnt /bin/bash"

Comment: Can't be the same error, lol. try `chroot /mnt`

Comment: Looking at the second error, your best fix is to back up your data and do a fresh install. Your only other option would be to manually download, unpackage (extract) the .deb, and manually copy the files over to the proper locations in /mnt

Answer (score 0):

What I did, was a fresh install. It felt like the only good solution.
I want to thank you all for your help!

Thanks!